# java.lang.NullPointerException from wrong return null?

Tags: android, okhttp

while I debbuging my test code I am having error in this line

```
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
```

with error `java.lang.NullPointerException` It seems `image` is getting empty

this is the code that I am getting the image

```
public class OkHttpHandler extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, byte[]> {

    private final String IMAGE_URL = "http://bit.ly/1DU2Zka";

    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

    @Override
    protected byte[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d("e", "dddddddddd");
        Log.d("e", IMAGE_URL);

        Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
        builder.url(IMAGE_URL);

        Request request = builder.build();

        try {

            Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();

            System.out.println(response);
            Log.d("e", "FFFFFF response");

            return response.body().bytes();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("e", "rrrrrrr");
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("e", "rrrrrrr");

        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

is this correct `return null;`?

and like this I am getting the image in `mainactivity`

```
    public void downloadImage() {
        OkHttpHandler handler = new OkHttpHandler();

        byte[] image = new byte[0];

        try {

            image = handler.execute().get();
            Log.d("e", "hhhh handler");
System.out.print(image);
            if (image != null && image.length > 0){
                Log.isLoggable("e",image.length);
                Log.d("e", "ddddddd entered the try");
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  //              txtBytes.setText("Total bytes downloaded: " + image.length);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("e", "rrrrrr error");

            e.printStackTrace();
//            txtBytes.setText("Hmm sorry, something went wrong!");
        }

    }
```

why I am getting nullpointerexception ?

logcat

```
10-11 16:55:22.724  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i D/e﹕ ddddddd entered the try
10-11 16:55:22.739  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i D/e﹕ rrrrrr error
10-11 16:55:22.739  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
10-11 16:55:22.739  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i W/System.err﹕ at com.justedhak.www.i.MainActivity.downloadImage(MainActivity.java:82)
10-11 16:55:22.739  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i W/System.err﹕ at com.justedhak.www.i.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
10-11 16:55:22.744  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
10-11 16:55:22.744  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
10-11 16:55:22.744  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
10-11 16:55:22.744  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
10-11 16:55:22.744  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
10-11 16:55:22.744  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
10-11 16:55:22.744  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-11 16:55:22.744  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
10-11 16:55:22.744  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
10-11 16:55:22.744  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-11 16:55:22.744  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-11 16:55:22.744  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
10-11 16:55:22.744  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
10-11 16:55:22.744  27814-27814/com.justedhak.www.i W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace so we can be sure where is it happening

Comment: @droidpl check my edit please. can you help me now ?

Comment: After the line "Log.d("e", "ddddddd entered the try");" something is null. I cannot guess, You can debug your code.

Comment: are you sure imageView is assigned?

Comment: @oguzhand the bitmap is being null . Sander i will double check

Comment: AsyncTask without onPostExecute()?

Comment: @BNK its an example anyway you are right I have to add onPostExecute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the problem is the allocation of image in your main program (before you enter the try block). You just reserve one byte, is this ok?

And then you try to pass an image to one byte which seems to produce the problem. Maybe Java just takes the first byte of the picture to your variable image. This is why you pass the if conditions but you fail if you try to create a bitmap.

good luck

Answer (score 1):

null pointer exception show when you do not initialize something properly. Check OnCreate method, Have you initialize everything properly ?